# MongoServerError: cursor not found

Tags: mongodb

Estoy tratando de arreglar el problema de que mi colección tiene un array grande, así que para ello me hice este script:

```
db.videoraw.find().forEach(function (videoraw) {
    var existingVideoTitle = db.video.findOne({
        _id: videoraw._id
    });

    if (!existingVideoTitle) {
        var newVideoTitle = {
            _id: videoraw._id,
            video_title: videoraw.video_title
        };
        db.video.insert(newVideoTitle);
    }

    videoraw.transcript.forEach(function (transcriptItem) {
        var existingTranscript = db.transcripts.findOne({
            video_id: videoraw._id,
            url: transcriptItem.url
        });

        if (!existingTranscript) {
            var transcriptData = {
                url: transcriptItem.url,
                text: transcriptItem.text
            };

            var newTranscript = {
                video_id: videoraw._id,
                url: transcriptData.url,
                text: transcriptData.text
            };
            db.transcripts.insert(newTranscript);
        }
    });
});
```

Pero obtengo el error al llegar al registro 92174 en la colección transcripts:

> MongoServerError: cursor id 3990877974918214127 not found

No recuerdo haber usado explícitamente cursores, y me gustaría saber como corregir ese error

Comment: Buen día, ¿Hay algún error en los logs de MongoDB? MongoDB Shell usa cursores internamente cuando se usa `foreach`, es posible que haya un poco más de información en el `logger`

Comment: Otra cosa que puedes intentar es agregar `addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout)` antes del `foreach`, de esta forma `db.videoraw.find().addOption(DBQuery.Option.noTimeout).forEach(function(videoraw)` para evitar el `timeout` por los cursores del `foreach` con colecciones grandes.

Answer (score 0):

Usé el método `batchsize` para hacer el procesamiento por lotes de 100 en 100, [aquí](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) pueden hallar la documentación.

Para iterar a los siguientes uso el método hasNext que como menciona [la documentación](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.hasNext/), avanza el cursor para que con una simple llamada a `find()` podamos tener los siguientes 100.

El script queda de la siguiente manera:

```
var batchSize = 100; // Procesar documentos por lotes de 100

var videorawCursor = db.videoraw.find().batchSize(batchSize);

while (videorawCursor.hasNext()) {
    var videorawBatch = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < batchSize && videorawCursor.hasNext(); i++) {
        videorawBatch.push(videorawCursor.next());
    }

    // Procesar un lote de documentos videoraw
    videorawBatch.forEach(function (videoraw) {
        var existingVideoTitle = db.video.findOne({
            _id: videoraw._id
        });

        if (!existingVideoTitle) {
            var newVideoTitle = {
                _id: videoraw._id,
                video_title: videoraw.video_title
            };
            db.video.insert(newVideoTitle);
        }

        videoraw.transcript.forEach(function (transcriptItem) {
            var existingTranscript = db.transcripts.findOne({
                video_id: videoraw._id,
                url: transcriptItem.url
            });

            if (!existingTranscript) {
                var transcriptData = {
                    url: transcriptItem.url,
                    text: transcriptItem.text
                };

                var newTranscript = {
                    video_id: videoraw._id,
                    url: transcriptData.url,
                    text: transcriptData.text
                };
                db.transcripts.insertOne(newTranscript);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Todavía no es lo máximo en desempeño, pero ya logré insertar más registros, ahora falla a los 152,701 registros

tal vez a alguien más le sirva este enfoque, yo seguiré intentando con distintos tamaños de batch antes de buscar otra forma de solucionar el problema

Gracias a HeytalePazguato, por orientarme a que sí se estaban usando cursores